# Lie algebra of the connected component of a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-isomorphism

This is probably trivial (hope not!), but I am *looking for a proof* that **if G is a Lie subgroup of H and G is also the connected component of H, then G and H have isomorphic Lie algebras**. If this does not hold, what other restrictions on G and H could make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: The Lie algebra is the tangent space at the identity. Tangent spaces depend only on a tiny neighborhood of a point. In particular they do not care about connected components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lie algebra "is" the tangent space at the identity, i.e. the derivatives at $t = 0$ of smooth curves $c(t)$ with $c(0) = e$.  These curves necessarily have range in the connected component, so you get the same result whether you consider the whole group or just the connected component.

Comment: Why do they have the range in the connected component?

Comment: The range of such a smooth curve $c: (-1, 1) \to  H$ is connected and contains the identity $e$, so is contained in the connected component of $e$.   The connected component is an open and closed subgroup of $H$, so is itself a Lie group.